# How to increase delay of ssh root access every time login fails

Tags: linux, ssh, access-control, brute-force

Is there a way in Linux to delay, for example double the delay time, of the ssh root access every time an ssh root login fails from a given IP and them let the delay expire after X minutes of no login attempts or success?

The aim is to mitigate brute force ssh/root access attacks to my servers.

I'm using Debian and Ubuntu.

Thank you.

Comment: As this is a specific Linux configuration question, I'm voting to migrate to SuperUser.

Comment: Just to be sure - can you use fail2ban? http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page there is no exponential backoff, but simply blocks an IP after N-attempts.

Comment: @schroeder I disagree as any security question applicable to Linux will involve some kind of Linux configuration unless it is a purely theoretical question (example http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/21027/invalid-users-trying-to-log-in-to-my-server?rq=1)

Comment: Exactly. Your question has security implications, but the heart of it is a specific configuration/tool question, which is off topic here and better suited for SuperUser.

Comment: I had migrated it to unix SE. But also I think this question has enough security focus to remain here, maybe unix SE is more better place for him (finally I voted with schroeder, only because I think migration is a good thing, but unix SE migration path doesn't exist).

Comment: Just because I mentioned Linux does not mean that the answer cannot have relevance for other OSes or the concepts be translatable to other contexts - I've mentioned "Linux", "Debian" and "Ubuntu" to provide context but ultimately the answer can have relevance beyond that. Besides http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/21027/invalid-users-trying-to-log-in-to-my-server?rq=1 got 25 up votes even if it is obviously Unix specific (root user, use of failtoban etc.), how come? I'd like to know.

Comment: @Wulfire The question is "how do I protect myself" which is a general question. The answer is general with specific tool mentions. The question is also 2.5 years old and the community has shifted a little since then. Your question is "how do I do this in Linux?"

Comment: @schroeder If you look around there are many other recent questions that are "Linux specific" including the first one here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured -- Sounds like we're going in circles, so I'll try my best to not repeat myself.

Comment: @Wulfire you are absolutely correct, but that can't be migrated because of the bounty. You will also see that the detailed answer references ServerFault.

Comment: Just trying to get this straight: It looks like you want to incrementally ban an IP address from trying to login as root unless and until it guesses the root password successfully. It can cancel that ban by guessing correctly, which means it's free to continue brute-forcing the authentication system at least. Are the authentication and ban implementations at different devices?

Comment: @vidar A nice incremental back-off is here: http://blog.shanock.com/fail2ban-increased-ban-times-for-repeat-offenders/ and builds off some concepts in the linked article here: http://serverfault.com/a/640380/246220

Comment: Do you use webmin?  What SSH access are you using, if any?  You can set access to a specific IP only, configure a dedicated router with said fixed IPA...there are several workarounds aside from a bash command, but you could try "set -m -t --T" without quotes...or some derivation of that...possibly

Comment: @ǝɲǝɲbρɯͽ as per question "the aim is to mitigate brute force ssh/root access attacks to my servers" so I'm open to anything that helps in that regard - being a non expert of security the first thing that came to my mind is to somehow slow down incrementally attempts to brute force root access, but as I said I'm open to any other methodology to "counter attack" such attempts.

Comment: @ Ian not using webmin (just plain old ssh/sshd) although good to know about it might be useful @ǝɲǝɲbρɯͽ @ vidar thanks for the various fail2ban links (which everyone seem to point me to) I really wish such security features were built-in the sshd itself in the form of a couple of config variables... Again, any other approach (besides the uninformed one I came up with of delaying failed login accesses) that in your opinion gets me closer to the main goal of "mitigating brute force ssh/root access attacks to my servers" is welcome. Thank you all for the feedback.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Unix&Linux SE.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is primarily Linux configuration, not really security. It addresses your aim but doesn't provide for resetting the timeout on a correct password or incrementing it while already banned. That probably has to be out of band, using some other event as a key.

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/640380/246220) links to an article showing how to deal with repeat offenders once, and [this](http://blog.shanock.com/fail2ban-increased-ban-times-for-repeat-offenders/) shows how to perform an incrementing ban. Since just linking is bad I'll try to rephrase what it's doing.

In effect, you want to create several configuration blocks that use nearly identical names; the author uses "f2b-loop2", "f2b-loop3", and so on. The DEFAULT block is the driver.

Each loop step uses the same filter. That filter ignores all loop-named bans but continues counting the DEFAULT bans over the scantime, effectively making level determine "How many times has DEFAULT banned this IP in my scan period/findtime?". The total attempts that trigger successively higher bantimes are therefore a multiplication of DEFAULT's maxtimes and the loop level's maxtimes.

You can continue this pattern to end with a negative bantime to permanently ban.

Comment: * I also voted to relocate this question because it feels very administrative.